# Sphinx Returning Wrong Amount Of Matches

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I have a MySql database with a table called 'table' let's say.

The table has two fields: ID (auto-increment primary key) and field (varchar).

A website accesses the database via a search bar which sends an ajax call to php which then queries sphinx as such:

```
// Sphinx Query
        $sphinx = new SphinxClient();
        $sphinx_index = 'index_field';
        $mode = SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN;
        $sphinx->SetServer("127.0.0.1", 122381);
        $sphinx->setLimits(0,1000); // max search results sphinx can return
        $sphinx->setMaxQueryTime(5000); // 5 seconds || 5000 milliseconds
        $sphinx->setMatchMode($mode);
        $sphinx->setFieldWeights(array('name' => 100));
        $sphinx->setArrayResult(true);
        $res = $sphinx->query($searchString,$sphinx_index);
```

When testing this, I found that querying for `$searchString = 'target';` returns 614 results.

When I go to MySql command line and type: `select count(*) from table where field='target';` it returns 624 results...

This is no good at all.

Here is the Sphinx source:

```
source src_field
{
    # data source type. mandatory, no default value
    # known types are 'mysql', 'pgsql', 'xmlpipe', 'xmlpipe2'
    type                    = mysql

    #####################################################################
    ## SQL settings (for 'mysql' and 'pgsql' types)
    #####################################################################

    # some straightforward parameters for SQL source types
    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user                = root
    sql_pass                = NotForYouToKnow
    sql_db                  = myDatabase
    sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query               = \
        SELECT a.ID AS ID, a.field AS field FROM table AS a;

    sql_ranged_throttle = 0

    sql_query_info      = SELECT a.ID AS ID, a.field AS field FROM table AS a WHERE a.ID=$ID;
}
```

And here is the Sphinx index:

```
index index_field
{
    # document source(s) to index
    # multi-value, mandatory
    # document IDs must be globally unique across all sources
    source          = src_field

    path            = C:\sphinx\data\index_field

    docinfo         = extern

    mlock           = 0

    morphology      = none

    min_word_len        = 1

    charset_type        = sbcs

    html_strip              = 0

        min_infix_len       = 2

        enable_star     = 1
}
```

I don't know why it would return almost the right amount of data but not all of it...

The length of the array that Sphinx spits out: `count($res) == 614`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is 'target' the actual query, or is it a more complicated possibly multiple word query?

Comment: @barryhunter The actual query is a one word query. But for this example I said 'target'

Comment: So what was your actual query? Providing examples is unhelpful. Its possibly something particular to the query in question. For example if its contains accents, it could be down to charset issues. Just guessing. Maybe try `select count(*) from table where binary field='target';`

Comment: @barryhunter Just tried `select count(*) from table where binary field='target';` and it returns the same count of `624`.

Comment: @barryhunter I'm now thinking that it was because I was using a very old version of Sphinx. I'm going to try to update my version of sphinx and see if it makes any difference.